# iOS provisioning profile expired

Tags: ios, testing, provisioning

We want to test our iOS app for 10 years later, i.e, 2021 etc. But when change time to 2021 from setting, and can not open the app again because the provisioning profile was expired.

How can I make such testing ?

Comment: Connect the iOS device the computer 10 years later and compile again?

Comment: You can't. Apple control the creation, distribution and management of provisioning profiles, and the maximum duration that one can have is 12 months.

Comment: Is that possible for us to purchase at least 5 years for the profile,then the validate duration will be at least 5 years, right ?

Answer (score 1):

Compute a timestamp for today + 10 years and feed that value into all date/time check functions in your app and see how it goes.

Comment: I assume that you have functions in your app that check time and date.  Check what they need and instead of a standard call to get system date and time, write a function that returns timestamp for today + 10 years.  That's what I would do.  Then, in the shipped code, I would turn "cheat code" off and use the standard date and time functions.

Comment: thanks, get it, but no. such functions were hidden by static library. :)